Proof of the associative law in scalars and Scalar's Transposition
While studying Properties of matrix addition and scalar multiplication, I saw the property $(k_1k_2)A=k_1(k_2A)$. (Here, $k_1, k_2$ are scalars.)
And I naturally thought that I have to prove it. But here, I thought that I should expand the number of scalars to three or more scalars, such as $k_1, k_2, k_3$. Of course, the associative law in real numbers or complex numbers is a very obvious fact, but if we prove it, we can prove it using very high-level mathematics. But I want to understand this proof in a way that I can understand, not using very high-level mathematics like Calculus or Linear Algebra. Using that, I want to prove the property $(k_1k_2)A=k_1(k_2A)$ very solidly. Of course, I know there is no reason to prove it like this, but I feel suspicious about passing it off like this, so I am asking this question.
Question: I would appreciate it if you could write about how to prove why the associative law is valid for the scalars $k_1, k_2, k_3$. And in the process of proving the above property, I wonder why we can move scalars around when calculating matrices or other mathematical objects.

Do I understand your 1st question correctly?: The associative law is valid for the scalars $k_{1}, k_{2}, k_{3}$ because these are elements of a given field (or ring) and the associative law comes along with a field (or ring) - it is a field (ring) axiom.
Could you give a few examples for your 2nd question?

For the first question, a mathematical way (high-level as you mentioned) to explain would be as Duong Ngo mentioned, that it is inherited from the field axioms. If you think it is too advance, then the answer would only be obvious.
For the second question, (assuming the associative law in scalars) the attacking plan would usually be write out each entries of the matrix on both sides explicity, and they would just addition and multiplication of scalars with some rearrangement. Thus, they are the same.

@DuongNgo Hello. Thanks for the comment. For the second question, as an example, if we think about properties of matrix as in the question, if there is a scalar $m$ and matrices $A, B$, then $mAB=AmB$ is valid, right? (Here, $mAB$ is the matrix product.) And if we think about polynomials, there are cases like $2x(x+1)=x2(x+1)$.

Writing $mA$ or $Am$ are valid and in fact they are the same thing when $A$ is a square matrix. This is valid because $mA = MA$ where $M = mI$ where $I$ is the identity (square) matrix whose number of columns equals the number of rows of $A$. Matrices like $M$ are called scalar matrices. Moreover, if $A$ is square then $AM = MA$, for any scalar matrix $M$ that is of the same size as $A$.

If we multiply a scalar $k_2$ by a matrix $A=(a_{ij})$, we get $$k_2A=(k_2a_{ij})$$. i.e. all of the entries in $A$ get multiplied by $k_2$.
Therefore, $$k_1(k_2A)=k_1(k_2a_{ij})=(k_1(k_2a_{ij}))=((k_1k_2)a_{ij})=(k_1k_2)A$$ because scalar multiplication is associative.
